# Characters go beyond the navigation bar in R Markdown Beamer

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

[image]

Hi everyone, I don't know why the letters go beyond the navigation bar... I used the theme: Berkeley and colortheme: dolphin.  Thank you!

Here is the code for some of my settings:

```
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    highlight: tango
    df_print: paged
    incremental: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
    df_print: kable
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tikzlings}
fontsize: 9pt
theme: Berkeley 
colortheme: dolphin
mainfont: Times New Roman
classoption: "aspectratio=169"
```

Comment: Good taste of latex packages you load :)

Answer (score 2):

Latex normally does not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, but you can give it a bit of a nudge:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
    highlight: tango
    df_print: paged
    incremental: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tikzlings}
fontsize: 9pt
theme: Berkeley 
colortheme: dolphin
classoption: "aspectratio=169"
---

# \texorpdfstring{Ex\-peri\-men\-tal}{Experimental} Design

## test

test
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!